# How can I bulk delete Google Apps sites that have been shared with me?

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites

I have about 60 sites that have been shared with me by my students. The students have long gone and I would like to get rid of those sites.

Instead of going one by one, is there a way to remove them in one batch.

I am using Google Apps for Education.

Answer (score 1):

Google APIs don't currently provide a way to delete Google Sites programmatically ([source](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/faq#DeleteSite)). This time, you'll need to delete them manually.

Going forward, I recommend that you have your students share the sites using the "People at  with the link", so that you can access the sites without having an entry in your ACL to remove later. See the selected option in the screenshot below.
[image: recommended site sharing option]